# Need help identifying this succulent (I think?)

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents, cactus

My grandma had started growing this for me awhile back and passed away in January before I could get much info on it... any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's called a Hoya carnosa compacta - a twisty leaved version of the well known [*Hoya carnosa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoya_carnosa) or Wax plant. It's a house plant favourite since it is easy to manage and can survive being ignored for a while.